# php not getting jquery post variables (works on one mac, not on other)

Tags: php, jquery, .post

I am encountering a very strange problem with jquery $.post and php.

My main page is calling the following function:

```
function sell(){
var table = document.getElementById('saleTab');
var count = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var listID = new Array();
var listPrice = new Array();
var listQTY = new Array();
count--;

var discount = document.getElementById('discountAmount').innerHTML;

while(count > 0){
    var allRow = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var allColumn = allRow[count].getElementsByTagName('td');
    listID[count-1] = allColumn[0].getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).value;
    listPrice[count-1] = allColumn[2].getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).value;
    listQTY[count-1] = allColumn[3].getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).value;
    count--;
}

$.post('handler/addSales.php',
    {id:listID, price:listPrice, qty:listQTY, discount:discount},
    function (data){
        //document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = data;
        //console.log(data);
    });
    location.reload();
```

}

When the function is called the variables are correctly sent to the addSales.php page.
firebug console reports the following post output when selling a theoretical single item:

```
discount    
id[]    itemname
price[] 5,50
qty[] 1
```

so the post variable are sent but the php file does not receive them properly.
here is the php file addSales.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../connection.php');
require_once('../functions.php');

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $count = count($id);
    $count--;
    $discount = euroToDollar($_POST['discount']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales (date, time, discount) values (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '$discount')") or die(mysql_error());
    $lastEntry = mysql_insert_id();

    while($count >= 0){
        $newPrice = euroToDollar($price[$count]);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales_item (salesID, itemID, qty, sellingPrice) VALUES ('$lastEntry', '$id[$count]', '$qty[$count]', '$newPrice')") or die(mysql_error());
        $newQTY = fetchRecord('item', 'qty', $id[$count]) - $qty[$count];
        //$newQTY = $newQTY - $qty[$count];
        mysql_query("UPDATE item SET qty = '$newQTY' WHERE id = '$id[$count]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $count--;
    }
}
mysql_close();
```

?>

Note that this script WORKS on my borther's macbook pro with mamp installed (php 5.4.10) and DOES NOT work on my macbook pro!
only 2 differences are: the mamp version. My macbook has latest mamp version (php 5.6.7). 
and the fact  I can NOT turn on xcache from mamp preferences on my mac (it stop/start server and goes back to disabled), while its turned on on my brother's laptop.
This is making me go crazy since I dont see a reason it should not work on my mac.

Any help appreciated,

This is what my error log states:

[07-May-2015 22:38:34 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GESTIONALE_BIRRE/index.php:2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GESTIONALE_BIRRE/index.php on line 3
[07-May-2015 22:38:34 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GESTIONALE_BIRRE/index.php:2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GESTIONALE_BIRRE/index.php on line 3

*UPDATE*
I have changed the scripts in all files to mysqli, and removed all sessions. the javascript sell function remained the same, and it sill send the variables through post method properly. 
the new addSales.php file code is:

```
 <?php
require('../connection.php');
require('../functions.php');

if($_POST){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $count = count($id);
    $count--;
    $discount = euroToDollar($_POST['discount']);

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sales (date, time, discount) values (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '$discount')");
    $lastEntry = mysql_insert_id();

    while($count >= 0){
        $newPrice = euroToDollar($price[$count]);
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sales_item (salesID, itemID, qty, sellingPrice) VALUES ('$lastEntry', '$id[$count]', '$qty[$count]', '$newPrice')");
        $newQTY = fetchRecord('item', 'qty', $id[$count], $mysqli) - $qty[$count];
        //$newQTY = $newQTY - $qty[$count];
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE item SET qty = '$newQTY' WHERE id = '$id[$count]'");
        $count--;
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Now the error log shows no error messages unlike before, but the addSales script still does not work.

Comment: `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.  I would suggest that the first thing you do would be to replace this usage with `mysqli` or `PDO` for database access.

Comment: Also, does the `euroToDollar()` function convert comma decimal separator with period as could be required based on database field type?

Comment: Finally, you have absolutely zero error handling around your database accesses.  You need to add code to handle unexpected failure and log our error messages.  This will aid you greatly in debugging code.

Comment: This cose is part of a small php management web app that was made for me. Unfortnately i have no way to contact the programmer. I can try to change the whole script to mysqli but i dont know if i'll succeed properly. For now i'll try to change only that specific php file to mysqli and post results.

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to update all the scripts myself so i have 2 possible solutions. Luckily find someone  with a specific solution to the script i posted (the only part of whole web applcation that doesnt work) Or someone who will recode the whole script for a small fee. It is a really basic project so shouldnt take long.

Comment: Finding someone to code for you is not what SO is about. Good luck.

Comment: The script will work on previous versions of PHP, because the error was raised on calling `require_once('../connection.php');` which does not work with PHP>5.5.

Comment: have changed the require_once to include. nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're seeing are unrelated to jQuery, they're saying that a session has already been started. Wherever you're calling `session_start`, you should call it like this:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start()
}
```

However, if your live server runs PHP < 5.4, you should do it like this:

```
if (session_id() == "") {
    session_start()
}
```

Comment: I have changed line 3 in index php from session_start() to your first option. I still get the same error message in log. using PHP 5.6.7

Comment: If you read the log, it tells you that `index.php` sent the headers, meaning some other file is trying to. Do a search in the codebase for `session_start` and make the same change

Comment: I have update all the files to mysqli and removed ALL the session_start or anything relative to sessions. The problem persists. check updated original post

Comment: OK in that case, it sounds like you have some other error or output that happens before `session_start` gets called

Comment: As I wrote before I removed all the session related script, so in fact there is no session, and the log error says nothing. This leaves me clueless

Answer (score 0):

Had to change all the scripts to mysqli for current php version and
it seems the problem was calling location.reload(); outside the $.post return in the javascript function. This  didnt let the function work properly.

So I changed the code from:

```
$.post('handler/addSales.php',
{id:listID, price:listPrice, qty:listQTY, discount:discount},
function (data){
    //document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = data;
    //console.log(data);
});
location.reload();
```

to:

```
$.post('handler/addSales.php',
{id:listID, price:listPrice, qty:listQTY, discount:discount},
function (data){
    //document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = data;
    //console.log(data);
    location.reload();
});
```

And it worked!!